# How to make this computation same like my calculator does

Tags: javascript

I am running the following script and getting a different result than expected. My desktop calculator calculates $28.84, but the code shows $29.07. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my code.

```js
// Compute Semi-monthly
function calcSalaryS() {
  var sppp3_element = document.getElementById('txt_sppp3');
  var sppp3 = parseInt(sppp3_element.value);
  var hours3_element = document.getElementById('txt_hours3');
  var hours3 = parseInt(hours3_element.value);
  var wwpy3_element = document.getElementById('txt_wwpy3');
  var wwpy3 = parseInt(wwpy3_element.value);
  var calculateS = sppp3 / wwpy3;
  var calculateSS = calculateS / hours3;
  var calculateS1 = sppp3 / 260;
  if (hours3 == 86.67) {
    document.getElementById('resultsS').innerHTML = 'Daily Rate $' + calculateSS.toLocaleString() + '<br>' + 'Hourly Rate $' + calculateS1.toLocaleString();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultsS').innerHTML = 'Daily Rate $' + calculateSS.toLocaleString() + '<br>' + 'Hourly Rate $' + calculateS1.toLocaleString();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Yearly Salary:<input type="text" name="sppp3" id="txt_sppp3" value="60000" size="12" title="Whole numbers only,e.g. '20000'" /></p>
<p>Hours Per Week:<input type="text" name="hours3" id="txt_hours3" value="86.67" size="10" disabled /></p>
<p>Work Week per Year:<input type="text" name="wwpy3" id="txt_wwpy3" value="24" size="7" disabled /></p>
<button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalaryS()" class="block">Compute Daily and Hourly Rate</button></p>
<p id="resultsS"></p>
```

Comment: If it's supposed to return 29.07, and that's what it returns, what's the problem? If the calculator is getting a different result, the problem must be with how you're doing it on the calculator.

Comment: I was trying to edit your question to turn your code samples into a runnable Stack Snippet. The edit seemed fine, but when run it produced "Daily Rate $29.07
Hourly Rate $230.769" ... the Hourly rate is much larger than the _Daily_ rate?

Comment: Since you haven't told us how you're calculating it on the desktop calculator, how can we tell what you're doing differently?

Comment: You are using `parseInt` to extract the number from `txt_hours3`, as a result you have `86` instead of `86.67`. Use `parseFloat` to properly get a fractional number.

Comment: Im sorry sir @barmar, its supposed to yield $28.84 and not $29.07. my sincere apologies

Comment: What's the point of that `if` statement? You do the same thing in both the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: sir @StephenP, my sincere apologies its just wrong labeling.

Comment: @blakkwater , your answer worked. thanks a lot. appreciate your help sir. to everyone my apologies im just new on the stackoverflow and also a newbie on learning the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you expect as result with the line

```
var hours3 = parseInt(hours3_element.value);
```

and as value "86.87" ?

The result is: hours3 = 86 !

You should use parseFloat() !

Comment: I don't think this answer really explains the difference between `parseFloat` and `parseInt` and why you need to use `parseFloat`. Adding an explanation to your code will make it much more useful for future readers.

Comment: Indeed, I could copy all the documentation for the 2 functions... But it seems more relevant to me to clearly show the difference between what seems to be expected and the actual result, to encourage people to think... That's more rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you want to yield $28.84 not $29.07 and to do that you can use `parseFloat` instead of `pasrseInt`

Comment: Can you explain **why** `parseInt()` doesn't work? This post doesn't add anything new from the other answer.

Comment: `parseInt()` is used to parse a string into an integer. `parseFloat()` parse strings and convert them into floating-point (with decimal values which the post prefers)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the other existing answers thoroughly explain the root issue of your code. Here's **why** it isn't working (in addition to the solution):

The problem is that your computer's calculator knows what fractions are, but your code doesn't. Throughout your code, you use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), however, this function only works with integers (whole numbers). If you pass a fraction to `parseInt`, it will *truncate* the fraction, or get rid of the fractional part. Because you're getting rid of data, you're going to get an inaccurate result.

What your want to use is [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). `parseFloat` does the same as `parseInt`, except it doesn't truncate anything. If you pass it a fraction, then its result will be fractional. This is what I mean by "`parseFloat` knows about fractions, but `parseInt` doesn't".

Some other comments/answers say that `parseInt` returns an integer and `parseFloat` returns a floating-point number, however, this isn't entirely true. Unlike other programming languages, there aren't different types of numbers like `int`, `double`, or `float` in JavaScript; all numbers are floating-point numbers (`float`), and both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` return floating-point numbers. The only difference is how they parse the input. `parseFloat` will take into consideration the fractional parts and `parseInt` won't.

Answer (score 1):

[blakkwater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10545492/blakkwater) provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493921/how-to-make-this-computation-same-like-my-calculator-does/76494004#comment134874799_76493921) on the question:

> You are using `parseInt` to extract the number from `txt_hours3`, as a result you have `86` instead of `86.67`. Use `parseFloat` to properly get a fractional number.

The result is:

```js
// Compute Semi-monthly
function calcSalaryS() {
  var sppp3_element = document.getElementById('txt_sppp3');
  var sppp3 = parseInt(sppp3_element.value);
  var hours3_element = document.getElementById('txt_hours3');
  var hours3 = parseFloat(hours3_element.value);
  var wwpy3_element = document.getElementById('txt_wwpy3');
  var wwpy3 = parseInt(wwpy3_element.value);
  var calculateS = sppp3 / wwpy3;
  var calculateSS = calculateS / hours3;
  var calculateS1 = sppp3 / 260;
  if (hours3 == 86.67) {
    document.getElementById('resultsS').innerHTML = 'Hourly Rate $' + calculateSS.toLocaleString() + '<br>' + 'Daily Rate $' + calculateS1.toLocaleString();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('resultsS').innerHTML = 'Hourly Rate $' + calculateSS.toLocaleString() + '<br>' + 'Daily Rate $' + calculateS1.toLocaleString();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Yearly Salary:<input type="text" name="sppp3" id="txt_sppp3" value="60000" size="12" title="Whole numbers only,e.g. '20000'" /></p>
<p>Hours Per Week:<input type="text" name="hours3" id="txt_hours3" value="86.67" size="10" disabled /></p>
<p>Work Week per Year:<input type="text" name="wwpy3" id="txt_wwpy3" value="24" size="7" disabled /></p>
<button value="calculate" onclick="calcSalaryS()" class="block">Compute Daily and Hourly Rate</button></p>
<p id="resultsS"></p>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" answers (you should delete this answer, or let it be deleted by the system). You can upvote and accept the answer that best helped you instead.